# IE8 crashes with all add-ons disabled in "Manage Add-Ons" GUI, but runs OK when launched with -extoff

Tags: windows, windows-xp, browser-addons, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to clean up an old Windows XP machine that had malware on it.  I ran a "quick scan" with Microsoft Security Essentials, which found and removed one "threat." [1]  However, I still have a problem....

When using IE8 to navigate to the [download page for Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/thankyou/activex/?installer=Reader_9.3_English_for_Windows), the tab crashes and I'm told that "A malfunctioning or malicious add-on has caused Internet Explorer to close this webpage" [2]  Consistent with this, if I start Internet Explorer without add-ons (`-extoff` command-line option), then I can load that page ok.

**But** if I use the "Manage Add-ons" window to disable every extension I can find [3], and then start IE normally (*without* `-extoff`) and navigate to that page, it crashes again!

I don't understand this.  **Could this crash be caused by some "hidden" extension that doesn't show up in the "Manage Add-ons" GUI, but is disabled by the `extoff` command-line switch?**  If so, how might I find it and remove it?

For the record, I've also tried "Reset Internet Explorer settings" (Internet Options > Advanced > Reset) but the tab still crashes.

---

[1] Before that, I ran TrendMicro's "HouseCall" tool but it found nothing.  Am currently running a full system scan with MSE.  Also have access to McAfee VirusScan, so I'll try that next.

[2] The full error message is long, but you can see it in IE at `res://ieframe.dll/acr_depnx_error.htm`    DEP is turned on system-wide (Control Panel > System > Advanced > Performance > Settings > Data Execution Prevention > "Turn on DEP for *all* programs...")  If I turn off DEP, then instead of getting that message when loading the page, IE just freezes completely.

[3] To disable "all" extensions, I did this: IE > Tools menu > Internet Options > Programs tab > Manage Add-ons.  There's a drop-down menu on the lower-left labeled "Show:".  For each drop-down menu item there, I selected all the extensions listed in the right-panel, right-clicked and chose "Disable All."

Comment: Spam filter prevented me from adding link to screen-shot of IE error message at http://a.yfrog.com/img8/978/capturecg.png

Answer (score 1):

Clean out your Temp folder, also your Temporary Internet Files folder.

Also run MBAM, install the program and then run the updater twice, then scan the system.
http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

if no joy, Check add/remove programs, see if you can uninstall IE8, then reinstall it.

.